# getting input data from VF page to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am trying to get a date value in a VF page and transfering it to a custom controller using a custom object reference Ticket__c. This says i am trying to deference a null object. How can i get the input from VF page into thee contoller.

```
<apex:inputField label="FromDate"  value="{!fromDate}" id="fromDate"/><br/>
<apex:inputField label="ToDate" value="{!toDate}" id="toDate"/><br/>
`
```

custom contoller

```
public class ReportController {

public DateTime fromDate;
public DateTime toDate;


public void fetchRecords()
{

system.debug(fromDate);
system.debug(toDate);
.
.
 //other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1: You need use property for data bindings

```
public DateTime fromDate {get; set;}
public DateTime toDate {get; set;}
```

2: `<apex:inputField>` you can use only with SObject, in that case appropriate control will be generated. In your your case, you need use `<apex:inputText>` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:input type="date" label="FromDate"  value="{!fromDate}" id="fromDate"/><br/>
<apex:input type="date" label="ToDate" value="{!toDate}" id="toDate"/><br/>
```

`
custom contoller

```
public class ReportController {

public Date fromDate;
public Date toDate;


public void fetchRecords()
{

system.debug(fromDate);
system.debug(toDate);
.
.
 //other code
}
```

You need to use apex:input with type date for this to working. But kee this thing in mind that this will not work with FF or other browser. Also keep your Doctype="html 5.0".

Second option is use apex:inputfield with some object field example: Opportunity close Date or any other field in this way you will get your value> when you submit the form you will get updated value in your controller.